# How do I move an object (Enemy) to a certain position

Tags: java, trigonometry, velocity

If I spawn 2 enemies at different 2D points, let's say (10,9) and (50,-1). And I want both of these objects to move to the same coordinate, let's say (30,15). How would I do this?

Here is my approach:

- Calculate `(y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)` for both points; where x2 = 30 and y2 = 15.
- Find the angle using Math.atan() on this number.
- Set the `dx` of the Enemy object to Math.cos() of this angle and `dy` to Math.sin() of this number.

However, when I calculate the angle it seems very off from what it should be.
For instance, I have the points of the Enemy that are `(-73,758)` and the points they need to move to which is `(574,350)`, but the angle it returns is `-32.235` degrees which makes no sense since that is the opposite direction.

Comment: If you set (-73,758) to a pseduo-origin of the xy-plane, would -32.235 degrees not be the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

if you try mapping the points in a graph, the enemy would be to the top left of the destination. so it would have to go  right and down simultaneously to reach the point. -32.235 is the same as 327.765 degrees